# How to create Action from text file on runtime c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, workflow-engine

I have a project, that implements WorkflowEngine Designer. This library support adding Code Actions in ActionProvider, just like this:  `_actions.Add("MyAction", MyAction);`

where second parameter is method name and _actions is a `Dictionary<string, <Action<ProcessInstance, WorkflowRuntime, string>>>`.

I can define this method in ActionProvider class, like this:

```
private void MyAction(ProcessInstance processInstance,
    WorkflowRuntime runtime, string actionParameter)
{
    var ss = "ss";
}
```

But what I need is Code Actions dynamically generated on runtime from text files outside the project. Those text files contains C# code and could be changed.

So how can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to add a new action? Why not create a single action and have the name be in the URL like Action/Do/{ActionName}?

Comment: I have implemented Workflowengine .Net, that have ability to run c# code (code actions) while scheme process of workflow is in progress. By default those actions were created from xml that was saved in database.  My employer want to use text files instead